# EntityFramework не поддтягивает объекты

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

Работа в AspNetCore c пакетом Identity. Создаю кастомную модель юзера, которую наследую от IdentityUser, в эту модель добавляю список List Posts.

```cs
public class AppUser:IdentityUser
{
    List<Post> Posts {get;set;}
}
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Text {get;set;}
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    public virtual AppUser Author {get;set}
}
```

После этого в своем контроллере добавляю эти записи в бд и сохраняю данные. В другом контроллере при попытке отобразить эти данные хочу указать авторство, для этого хочу обратиться к post.Author.Name. Но свойство Author ссылается на null. UserId проставляется корректно.

Пока обхожу это тем, что в контроллере отображения получаю по Id нужного мне юзера из бд, и предварительно проставляю его в post.Author вручную, но думаю, что это не совсем правильный подход. До этого создавал иные приложения с EntityFramework без Identity, модели подтягивались сами. Есть ли у вас догадки, в чем может быть проблема ?
UPD. Использую EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: Укажите, какую именно версию EF используете. Подгрузка связанных данных выполняется по разному в разных версиях. EF6: [Loading Related Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/), EF Core: [Loading Related Entities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо! По прикрепленным ссылка все понял